# Where can I ask questions about TVs?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I have this question:

> I have a [LG 42LM3410](http://www.lg.com/in/tvs/lg-42LM3410/technical-specifications). The TV has an inbuilt USB2.0 port for playing media files *(videos, audios and photos)* on the go. The TV supports limited type files (I don't know full list of formats it supports but I have played `.mp4` and `.mov` files).
>
> On the other hand I was unsuccessful to play `.wmv`, `.wma`, `.flv` and some other file types.
>
> If TV plays videos, if might have some kind of softwares/codecs to play it. How can I make it able to support **x** formats with **y** open source codec available? Virtually I want it to support type of formats, like VLC does. How can I hack into my TV? For this, I don't care if my warranty is void.

Yes, I'm asking this from a programming point of view, but it is also related to consumer electronics *(This is why I am asking this question on Meta Stack Exchange)*.

Which Stack Exchange site is appropriate for this question?

Comment: Time for the obligatory [votes are different on meta comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).  The downvotes might be a disagreement that it is a a bit of programming.  That is the only think I can guess

Comment: *Are you coming at this form a software angle*; **yes**. Actually I posted a sample question here, I was about to post the whole question on the suggested site with more detail. BTW I had updated the question now.

Comment: There was a site for that, gadgets.stackexchange.com.  It got closed, mostly because the questions just didn't have enough in common to keep enough visitors coming back.  There's a new try at it here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33064/consumer-electronics

Comment: or here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Where can I ask questions about TVs?

---

### Super User

> Questions regarding the functionality and usage of TVs to watch broadcast programmes are off-topic.
>   <sub>-[Tag excerpt for TV](https://superuser.com/tags/tv/info) on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)</sub>

Based on the list of [top TV-related question](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tv?sort=votes) and [Journeyman Geek's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165958/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-tvs/298678#comment971058_298678), questions relating to computers interacting with televisions should be on-topic. This can involve using TV screens as a computer monitor, or connecting wirelessly to a Smart TV.

**[Examples of on-topic questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tv?sort=votes)**:

- [How can I stream a game through VLC to my TV?](https://superuser.com/q/447010/358766)
- [How to watch videos on Sony Bravia TV through LAN?](https://superuser.com/q/320766/358766)
- [Why doesn't a 4K TV give 4K resolution?](https://superuser.com/q/1023273/358766)

---

### Electrical Engineering

> Use this tag for technical aspects of TV (video formats, for example). Shopping questions are off-topic and repair questions might be too localized.
>   <sub>-[Tag excerpt for TV](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/tv/info) on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)</sub>

**[Examples of on-topic questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv?sort=votes)**:

- [Generating PAL tv signal using a PIC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/3083/149004)
- [TV screen in still photo: Why are there dark, blackish bands?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/251104/149004)
- [What is the function of "Picture tube charger"?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/243414/149004)

---

### Stack Overflow

> Questions directly relating to the development of TV apps, TV web apps, second screen experiences, etc.
>   <sub>-[Tag excerpt for TV](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tv/info) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)</sub>

**[Examples of on-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tv?sort=votes)**:

- [Can I display the current live TV feed in a full screen googleTV app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8260368/3357935)
- [Having issue with Apple TV view in interface builder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33736339/3357935)
- [Set active source to TV with cec-client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17506515/3357935)

---

### Internet of Things

> **Content Delivery aspects of a "smart TV" are not really IoT topics** - they're simply "yet another way to sell you media", and indeed, that is quite consistent with the previous question about using a "compute stick" to drive a TV.
>
> **However, using a "smart TV" to interface to a home control system could well be on topic** - the topic worthiness coming from the control of gadgets in the home, not from the "smart TV".
>   <sub>-[Chris Stratton on whether Smart TVs questions are allowed](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/a/310/2853) on [Internet of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/)</sub>

If your issue is *specifically* related to exploit vulnerability, network infrastructure, or remotely controlling a Smart TV, [Internet of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) ***might*** be a fitting place to ask.

> Internet of Things Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for users of everyday objects embedded with electronics to be ***sensed, monitored, and controlled remotely***.
>   <sub>-[Tour page](https://iot.stackexchange.com/tour) for [Internet of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/)</sub>

**[Examples of on-topic questions](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-tv?sort=votes)**:

- [Is my Samsung Smart TV vulnerable to the "weeping angel" attack?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/1233/2853)
- [How to debug a DLNA infrastructure?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/579/2853)
- [What ports does an LG TV open?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/1690/2853)

---

### Signal Processing

> Signal Processing is a question and answer site for users interested in the theory and applications of analog and digital signal processing, image processing and computer vision.
>   <sub>-[Tour page](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tour) for [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)</sub>

If your question is *specifically* about understanding the video and audio frequencies of television, [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/high-audio-frequencies-in-television-broadcast) is where to ask.

**[Examples of on-topic questions](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=television%20is%3Aq)**:

- [High audio frequencies in television broadcast](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/35643/29862)
- [Why do we choose 44.1 kHz as recording sampling rate?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/17685/29862)
- [Slow Scan TV Documentation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/340/29862)

---

### Movies & TV

> Movies & TV is a question and answer site for Movie and Television enthusiasts.
>   <sub>-[Tour page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tour) for [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)</sub>

For the sake of completeness, if your question is about a specific movie or television show, you can ask on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/).

**[Examples of on-topic questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes)**:

- https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/827/48480
- https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9745/48480
- https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2190/48480

Comment: The tag exerpt does not match with what you said - IF your TV is plugged into a PC, it could be on topic. Otherwise, no. That's not 95%. OP's specific question would certainly be off topic

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I've updated the site scope for Super User